# Why polars date time subseting is slow?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I'm looking for a faster way to subset a polars dataframe using datetime. I tried 2 different ways and I believe there is a faster way since I also tried with pandas and it was faster:

```
datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 3, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 3, 0, 0)


# - 1st
%%timeit
df_window = df_stock.filter(
    (df_stock["date_time"] >= start_date)
    & (df_stock["date_time"] <= end_date)
)
# 2.61 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# - 2nd
%%timeit
df_window = df_stock.filter(
    (pl.col("date_time") >= start_date) & (pl.col("date_time") <= end_date)
)
# 12.5 ms ± 801 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Pandas's subsetting is faster for datetime.

```
df_test = df_stock.to_pandas()
df_test.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)

%%timeit
df_test['2009-8-3':'2009-8-3']
# 1.02 ms ± 108 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So why pandas faster than polars in this case? Is there a faster form of subsetting datetime on polars?

Enviroment:

- Spyder version: 5.4.0 (conda)
- Python version: 3.8.13 64-bit
- Operating System: Linux 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: You return a copy of the filtered dataframe in the Polars code, and a view for Pandas. To do the same for Pandas, you should add a `.copy()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this just be an issue of benchmarking a relatively small query?  My benchmarking shows the exact opposite.

##### Data

Let's start with a good amount of data, so that the subsetting process represents the largest share of the work.  I'll also `shuffle` the data, so that issues of "sortedness" are not involved.

```py
import time
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df_stock = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_time": pl.date_range(
            low=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            high=datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            interval="1s",
        ).shuffle(seed=0)
    }
)
df_stock
```

```
shape: (725846401, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date_time           │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-02 21:46:35 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2003-12-16 18:57:19 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2018-06-20 14:31:08 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-04-09 07:18:38 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2013-07-12 00:39:09 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-09-08 17:18:59 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2010-08-18 16:00:18 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2010-02-06 05:13:05 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

725 million records should be a good start.

##### Test Cases

I've put together the three cases from your code into separate tests.

Test #1

```py
start_date = datetime(2009, 8, 3, 0, 0)
end_date = datetime(2009, 11, 3, 0, 0)

start = time.perf_counter()
_ = df_stock.filter(
    (df_stock["date_time"] >= start_date) & (df_stock["date_time"] <= end_date)
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Test #2

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
_ = df_stock.filter(
    (pl.col("date_time") >= start_date) & (pl.col("date_time") <= end_date)
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Test #3

```py
df_test = df_stock.to_pandas()
df_test.set_index("date_time", inplace=True)
start = time.perf_counter()
_ = df_test["2009-8-3":"2009-11-3"]
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Here are the timings for three runs of the above on my system (a 32-core system).

Test #1: 1.1206, 1.1199, 1.1202

Test #2: 0.8342, 0.8215, 0.8227

Test #3: 4.6082, 4.5932, 4.6185

On my system, the Pandas indexing runs the slowest - by far.  I could run this more than three times, but I think the pattern is quite clear.

Can you run a larger test on your system?  Perhaps there is something else at play here...

For reference, version information on my test environment ...

```
---Version info---
Polars: 0.15.7
Index type: UInt32
Platform: Linux-5.15.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Python: 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
---Optional dependencies---
pyarrow: 10.0.1
pandas: 1.5.2
numpy: 1.24.0
fsspec: 2022.11.0
connectorx: 0.3.1
xlsx2csv: 0.8
matplotlib: 3.6.2
```

Comment: Excelent answer, it is probably due the small dataset